# How to track updated_at in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I currently track updated_at in my mongodb(mongoose) collection using pre-save. Setter also doesn't work as I dont want user to also give me updated time everytime.

Is there any better way ie at the schema level to save updated time in my document?

I dont have pre-save in every collection and does not sound like a good idea to create pre-save for saving updated time

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
    updated: {
        type : Date, 
        default: Date.now
    }
})

OrderSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    this.updated = Date.now();
    next();
})
```